# SED command - MAC address

Tags: sed

I use the MAC address of the machine as userid and would like to update a file (display.txt) that will display the userid/expiry. How do I replace the *expdate* in *display.txt* with the date in *expdate.txt* corresponding to the MAC address.

I succeed with the userid part, with:

```
sed -i "s/user/$(ifconfig eth0 |
                 grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}')/" \
/user/id/display.txt > /dev/null
```

---

display.txt:

```
UserID: user
User expiring on expdate
```

---

expdate.txt:

```
user                          = 00:09:34:2C:66:AB
expdate                       = 2017-05-20
user                          = 00:09:34:29:86:6C
expdate                       = 2017-08-23
```

---

I would like to have:

display.txt:

```
UserID: 00:09:34:29:86:6C
User expiring on 2017-08-23
```

Comment: do you want to loop it through users and expiry dates. Or only one is enough?

Comment: Which operating system do you use?

Comment: all machines will download the same file and upon booting it will pull uses the mac address as the user and then find its expiring date from this file (expdate.txt).

Answer (score 0):

I found a one-liner solution using grep and sed:

```
mac=$(ifconfig eth1 | grep -o -E '([[:xdigit:]]{2}:){5}[[:xdigit:]]{2}'); grep "$mac" expdate.txt -A 1 | sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s!user.*=.(..\:..\:..\:..\:..\:..).*expdate.*=.(....-..-..)!UserID: \1\nUser expiring on \2!g' > display.txt
```

and to validate it works with any mac address I tested with:

```
mac=$(echo "00:09:34:29:86:6C") ; grep "$mac" expdate.txt -A 1 | sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s!user.*=.(..\:..\:..\:..\:..\:..).*expdate.*=.(....-..-..)!UserID: \1\nUser expiring on \2!g' > display2.txt
```

I generated the output from scratch, if you need a replacement in an existing file, I suggest to use a templating language like [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/). The Bash version is on [GitHub](https://github.com/tests-always-included/mo)

However because it seems you need to re-use the mac address (for searching first and then for the output) I suggest to make a bash script 
and it would be more re-usable.

Answer (score 0):

By concatenating `sed` outputs:

```
sed -e 's/user/UserID/g' expdate.txt | sed -e 's/ //g' | sed -e 's/=/: /g' | sed -e 's/expdate:/User expiring on/g' > display.txt
```

(It's pretty sure that this could be done also with only one `sed`)